# Inserting new elements to form causing issue when form is sent (empty data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have to forms on my website, when second form is filled up (after click save button) im copying this form and inserting it into first form. Unfortunately when I submit this form, data in inserted elements are empty.

My code:

```
 var objToCopy = $('.partnersForm').find('.modal-body').clone();

     objToCopy.find('[name]').each(function(){
                    var objThs = $(this);
                    objThs.prop('name', '_' + objThs.prop('name'));
                    objThs.prop('id', '_' + objThs.prop('id'));
                });
     $('.partnersData').html(objToCopy);
```

And data looks like this:

```
        [contact_county] => Hampshire
        [country] => GB
        [contact_title] => 4
        [contact_name] => gfhf
        [contact_surname] => fghfgh
        [_partner_mobile] => 
        [_partner_nationality] => 
        [_partner_dob] => 
        [_partner_email] =>
```

Where empty data come from inserted elements.
When I remove second form manually after insertion, then everything seems to work.
But I don't understant why I cant send this data even when I change names of inputs.

Simplified HTML structure:

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="contact_county" id="contact_county">
    <input name="country" id="country">
    <input name="contact_title" id="contact_title">
    <input name="contact_name" id="contact_name">
    <input name="contact_surname" id="contact_surname">
    <div class="partnersData" id="partnersData">
        <!-- inserted elements goes here -->
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form class="partnersForm" id="form2">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" name="partner_mobile" id="partner_mobile">
        <input type="text" name="partner_nationality" id="partner_nationality">
        <input type="text" name="partner_dob" id="partner_dob">
        <input type="text" name="partner_email" id="partner_email">  
    </div>
    <div class="modal-foter">
        <a href="#" class="copyElements">Save</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to post your html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$('.partnersForm').find('.modal-body').clone();`, you should use `$('.partnersForm').find('.modal-body').clone(true);`. When you are making the clone, only the form and associated controls are getting cloned, but the values are getting emptied. Passing "true" as the parameter to clone, the values inside the control will also get cloned.

For details, Check the JQuery Documentation to [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not fix my problem, I did what you suggest, but still after sending form I receiving empty data. After I copy those input have value, I can console log it.

Comment: I created this fiddle based on your code, [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JPvP4/) and if you click on "Submit" after "Save", you will find the Partners Data in the alert, otherwise the alert won't come at all.

Comment: Yes, this is my problem, I know that data are inside form after copy elements. Somehow after I sent it they are lost and in post data those inputs are empty...

Comment: Can you please specify the code being used for posting the data.